# Вызов виртуальной функции в конструкторе

Tags: c++, конструктор, полиморфизм

Имеется класс с конструктором по умолчанию, который использует методы класса. Хотелось бы в `main` создать динамический массив экземпляров класса таким образом, чтобы для каждого из элементов массива срабатывал конструктор по умолчанию. Как это сделать?

Вот часть кода. Методы в конструкторе не срабатывают при инициализации массива.

```
class Vect
{
protected:
    int cs;
public:
    Vect()
    {
        set_v();
    }
    virtual void set_v(){}
};

class Vect1 : public Vect
{
public:
    Vect1() : Vect(){}
    void set_v();
};

int main()
{
    int k=5;
    Vect1 *vect= new Vect1[k];
}

void Vect1::set_v()
{
    cout << "Выберите функцию-элемент вектор-функции:" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Что вкладывается в понятие `динамический массив`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При динамическом (через оператор `new`) создании массива экземпляров класса для каждого создаваемого экземпляра не только выделяется место, но и вызывается конструктор по умолчанию. Возьмём следующий пример кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Class {
    private :
        void f() {
            static int counter = 0;
            printf("Instance #%i.\n", counter++);
        }
    public :
        Class() {
            f();
        }
};

int main() {
    Class* array = new Class[10];
    return 0;
}
```

Компилируем и запускаем (компилятор `MinGW`):

```
g++ -s -o test.exe test.cpp && test.exe
```

Видим следующий вывод:

```
Instance #0.
Instance #1.
Instance #2.
Instance #3.
Instance #4.
Instance #5.
Instance #6.
Instance #7.
Instance #8.
Instance #9.
```

Из вывода видно, что для каждого экземпляра класса, расположенного в массиве, был вызван конструктор и выполнена функция из класса.

**Обновление**

Ага! Кажется, я понял в чём Ваша проблема. Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Class {
    private :
        virtual void f() {
            printf("Class::f()");
        }
    public :
        Class() {
            f();
        }
};

class Class1 : public Class {
    private :
        void f() {
            printf("Class1::f()");
        }
    public :
        Class1() : Class() {
            f();
        }
};

int main() {
    Class* array = new Class[1];
    return 0;
}
```

Если его запустить, то получаем следующий вывод:

```
Class::f()
```

а вовсе не `Class1::f()` как, вроде бы, ожидалось. Это связано с тем, что виртуальные функции в конструкторах не выполняются. Внутри конструктора всегда будет выполнена либо функция из самого класса, либо из его предка.

Если очень коротко, то ***внутри конструкторов и деструкторов модификатор `virtual` теряет силу***.

Comment: Начал писать до появления Вашего ответа)

Comment: @andy.37 Ничего страшного. ;-)

Comment: Знаю, не положено говорить спасибо в комментариях, но спасибо большое!

Comment: @АлександрЕфремов Рад был помочь! P.S. В `C++` много тонкостей. Про эту я знаю только потому, что сам как-то на неё напоролся... ;-)

Comment: "виртуальные функции в конструкторах не выполняются" и "внутри конструкторов и деструкторов модификатор virtual теряет силу" - это довольно грубые упрощения, которые мало соответствуют действительности. Более корректное описание поведения см. здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767168/Странная-и-непонятная-ошибка/767173#767173

Answer (score -1):

Нужно разбираться, что именно не срабатывает, и почему

a.h:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() { setX(0); }
    ~A() {}
    int value() const { return x; }
private:
    int x;
    void setX(int x) { this->x = x; }
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    A a;
    cout << a.value() << endl;
    A x[2];
    cout << x[0].value() << x[1].value() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Компилируется и работает, как и должно.