# Странная и непонятная ошибка

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте! Написал достаточно простой код:

```
class bar1
{
public:
    bar1()
    {
        foo();
    }

    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class bar2 : bar1
{
public:
    bar2() {}

    void foo() {}
};

int main()
{
    bar2 b;

    return 0;
}
```

Но он выдаёт непонятную ошибку:

> LNK2019   ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: virtual void __thiscall bar1::start(void)" (?start@bar1@@UAEXXZ) в функции "public: __thiscall bar1::bar1(void)" (??0bar1@@QAE@XZ)

Причем, если убрать строчку с вызовом виртуального метода foo, то все работает. Я догадываюсь, в чем здесь дело. Возможно, когда bar2 наследуется от bar1, вызывается конструктор bar1 и в нем вызывается еще не определенный метод foo, т.е. метод, еще не имеющий тела. Так ли это? И как это исправить?

Comment: Да, Вы правы. Не вызывать абстрактные методы в конструктoре базового класса.

Comment: Во-первых, тема, ранее предложенная в качестве дубликата (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/469288/Вызов-виртуальной-функции-в-конструкторе), не содержит ничего относящегося к сути данной темы в тексте самого вопроса. Во-вторых, выбранный в пердлагающемся дубликате ответ содержит грубые упрощения вида "виртуальные функции в конструкторах не выполняются" (?) и "внутри конструкторов и деструкторов модификатор virtual теряет силу" (?), которые по моему мнению несколько режут слух в рамках принятых на SO стандартов качества ответов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Виртуальные вызовы, выполняемые во время работы конструктора (или деструктора), ведут себя так, как будто иерархия классов заканчивается на том классе, чей конструктор (деструктор) активен в данный момент. Классов ниже в иерархии "как будто" не существует.

В вашем случае во время работы конструктора класса `bar1` все виртуальные вызовы будут работать так, как будто иерархия классов заканчивается на классе `bar1`, а класса `bar2` не существует в иерархии вообще. Вызов виртуальной функции `foo()` будет являться вызовом `bar1::foo()`. Так как эта функция является pure, поведение вашего кода не определено.

На практике конкретные целевые функции для виртуальных вызовов, выполненных непосредственно из конструктора, ясны еще на стадии компиляции. Компилятор в такой ситуации обычно оптимизирует код: он не порождает виртуального вызова, а порождает обычный прямой вызов конкретной функции. В вашем случае это вызов `bar1::foo()`. Так как тела функции `bar1::foo()` не существует, линкер не может слинковать этот вызов. Т.е. в данном случае неопределенное поведение выливается в ошибку на этапе линковки.

- Если вы немножко "замаскируете" ваш виртуальный вызов, т.е. сделаете его не непосредственно из конструктора, а через какую-нибудь промежуточную функцию

  ```
  class bar1
  {
  public:
      bar1()
      {
          baz();
      }

      void baz()
      {
          foo();
      }

      virtual void foo() = 0;
  };
  ```

  то компилятор скорее всего уже не сможет выполнить такой оптимизации. Такой код может скомпилироваться, но приведет к падению программы во время выполнения из-за попытки вызвать несуществующую виртуальную функцию.
- Если же вы в оригинальном варианте кода таки снабдите свою pure виртуальную функцию собственным телом

  ```
  void bar1::foo() 
  {
  }
  ```

  то код, возможно, даже успешно скомпилируется (и слинкуется). Однако формально его поведение по-прежнему не определено.

Об этом надо помнить, используя полиморфизм из конструктора или деструктора: работать в такой ситуации будет только "ограниченный" полиморфизм, который "заканчивается" на классе, чей конструктор (деструктор) активен в данный момент. Если вам нужно реализовать некую полиморфную инициализацию, то простейшим решением будет *двухфазная* инициализация: сначала вы даете возможность отработать конструкторам классов (первая фаза, неполиморфная), а затем самостоятельно вызываете еще какой-то дополнительный метод `init()`, который выполнит уже вторую фазу инициализации с полноценно работающим полиморфизмом.

Comment: хорошо переписываете