# Вызов виртуальных методов в конструкторе

Tags: c++, virtual

Я знаю, что виртуальные методы ведут себя в конструкторах совсем не так, как ожидается. Но мне не совсем ясно, можно ли вызывать виртуальный метод в конструкторе производного класса?

Примерно вот так:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
    int a;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B()
    {
        f();
    }
    void f() override
    {
        cout << "B::f()" << endl;
    }
    int b;
};
```

Могут ли в этом случае возникнуть проблемы? Если да, то в чем они будут заключаться?

Comment: И? Этот код содержит только объявления. Какие могут быть "проблемы" в коде, который ничего не делает?

Comment: Вызывать можно, просто он не будет виртуальным. Вызовется метод из того же класса. Вызов виртуального метода из другого класса в иерархии тоже возможен с явной спецификацией, например `B::f();`.

Comment: @freim: С чего бы это вдруг он "не будет виртуальным"?

Comment: @AnT, до чего же любите вы докопаться на пустом месте. Он будет вызван как невиртуальный - устроит такая формулировка?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не ясно, о каких именно проблемах вы говорите.

Как уже не раз говорилось, механизм вызова виртуальных методов в конструкторах работает так, как будто динамический тип объекта определяется работающим в данный момент конструктором. Во всех остальных отношениях виртуальный механизм работает как обычно.

В вашем примере, в соответствии с этим правилом, во время работы конструктора класса `B` с точки зрения виртуального механизма конструируемый объект будет иметь тип `B`. Соответственно виртуальный вызов метода `f` из конструктора `B::B` попадет в реализацию `B::f`.

Никаких проблем здесь нет.

В таком тривиальном примере как ваш, большинство компиляторов сразу "догадаются", что вызван будет именно метод `B::f` и *соптимизируют* виртуальный вызов, заменив его на обычный прямой вызов. В более хитрых случаях (вроде вызова через указатель) вызов останется виртуальным, но все равно будет работать корректно (учитывая описанное выше).

См.
[Вызов виртуального метода в конструкторе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604553/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5)
[Странная и непонятная ошибка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767168/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0/767173)

Comment: Больше спасибо за разъяснение. Тогда я не совсем понимаю, почему все говорят, что звать виртуальные методы в конструкторах нельзя... То, что при работе конструктора используется метод того класса, чей конструктор сейчас работает, вполне понятно. Очевидно, что в конструкторе предка не получится вызвать виртуальный метод наследника, потому что наследника еще не существует. Собственно, поэтому я и не понимаю, какие могут быть проблемы.

Comment: @MGNeo: "все говорят, что звать виртуальные методы в конструкторах нельзя" - это чушь. Не надо слушать таких "всех". Вызывать, разумеется, можно. Надо лишь понимать, как это будет работать при таком вызове.

Comment: большое спасибо за помощь!